# Can't Get React Component to Update or Pass Prop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

All the code does is to update a counter +1 every time you click in the button, the problem here is when i'm trying to pass the prop counter to text it does not update in the Text component i've been doing some research and look like i have to wake it up with another function, if someone could explain me, i would be really grateful.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {counter: 1}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => {
        this.setState({
          counter: this.state.counter+1
        });

          //tries passing  the prop counter with the state of the counter
          <Text counter={this.state.counter} /> 
          
    }}>
        Click here
      </button>
    )
  }
}
class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // returns 'clicked undefined times'
      <h2 id='counter-text'>{'Clicked ' + this.props.counter + ' times'}</h2>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text/>
        <Button/>
      </>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You are trying to render a `Text` component in where the `Button` props are, and the `Text` component rendered by `App` isn't passed any props. Lift the `counter` state up to the parent `App` component and pass the props down to each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the code is syntactically wrong.
You cannot render a `Text` in the `onChange` method of a button.

What you wanted was, when the count is updated in the Button, it should reflect in another component, i.e., the Text.

As these two are different components altogether, you have to have a shared state for them.

And for that, you can lift the `counter` state from `Button` to a parent component `App`. Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

This should work:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // 3. on every click, Button uses App's updater method to update the count
    return <button onClick={this.props.handleCounter}>Click here</button>;
  }
}
class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h2 id="counter-text">{"Clicked " + this.props.counter + " times"}</h2>
    );
  }
}

// 1. Let App bear the counter state
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 1 };
    this.handleCounter = this.handleCounter.bind(this);
  }

  handleCounter() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  }

  // 2. Let the Button and Text components share the App state
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text counter={this.state.counter} />
        <Button
          counter={this.state.counter}
          handleCounter={this.handleCounter}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: All good, i was finally coming to the same solution after seeing how to lift state worked, at the end i had to check your solution for some help because i had decided to not get spoiled, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mistakes on how your code is written.
I've changed it slightly and put it on a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-williamson-swjrn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) you can play around with.

What's wrong:

- You're trying to render `<Text counter={this.state.counter} />`  from
  within the onClick callback for the button, but this won't ever
  render without being inside the return statement of a render
  function.
- You're using state inside the Button component, but Text  component is not a child of this component.

  - Both `Button` and `Text` are children of `App`, and both of them need
    to access this counter state, so App should have the state and pass
    it as prop for `Text`
  - Button needs a callback to be able to update it's parent (App) state. You can pass a function that does this as a prop to `Button` and then call this on `onClick`.

Comment: also thank you, you have me an idea. also very intuitive, thanks for the sandbox